# Proposed tag restructuring: performance-tuning and speed

Tags: discussion, tagging

There are two tags, [performance-tuning](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance-tuning) and [speed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speed) that by present tag wiki are essentially duplicates:

- Questions about optimizing code for faster results, or how to do faster computations.
- Questions on optimizing Mathematica code for higher performance. This may mean faster execution, lower memory usage, or both. Use mathematical-optimization instead for minimization/maximization of objective functions.

I realize that [performance-tuning](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance-tuning) covers more than speed alone.  Perhaps every question with that tag should be co-tagged with either [memory](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memory) or [speed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speed). (Or some other performance aspect.)  If this is what you prefer post it as an answer please.  For my proposal see my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Co-tagging with `speed` or `memory` is what I would suggest.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=8609737#8609737)

---

I think [internal-function-performance](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internal-function-performance) is borderline micro-tagging, which will quickly become impractical (we're starting to have way too many micro tags). More importantly, the tag will not be allowed by the system since it is 29 characters in length. The max allowed is 25.

Comment: And do you think that [tag:speed] and [tag:memory] should be used **exclusively** with PT? If so, this needs explicit stating in their wikis and, more importantly, a lot of weeding as newcomers rarely read wikis.

Comment: @IstvánZachar No, I believe they can be used by themselves as well. For instance, a question like "Why does this leak memory" would not require PT. I can't think of an example right now for speed, but Mr.Wizard's first sentence seems like a good idea for speed without PT...

Answer (score 1):

I propose redefining [speed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speed) to be used for questions about the speed of existing *Mathematica* functions, rather than about performance tuning.  This is how I have subconsciously using the tag.  A question could still be co-tagged with both, but rather than the implication of *performance-tuning-for-speed* it would mean that the question was about both the specific performance of *Mathematica* internal functions, and how to optimize code.

Arguably it would be more descriptive and broad to use something like [performance](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) or [internal-function-performance](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internal-function-performance) instead of [speed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speed) but it doesn't seem better in practice.  Please comment with thoughts on this matter.